# Testing Restify services with Mocha-Cakes, and Coffescript, use of done() in async causes timeout issues

Tags: testing, coffeescript, mocha.js, restify, mocha-cakes

I am running into some timing issues with some [mocha-cakes](/questions/tagged/mocha-cakes) test scripts that run against [restify](/questions/tagged/restify) services. I'm using the Restify JSON client to issue the calls, which use callbacks rather than promises. I've passed in the done function to my `Given`s and `When`s, so that I can perform the necessary blocking against these async calls, which prevents inconsistent test suite runs (without the dones, it's a tossup which and how many `Then`s and `And`s will pass).

I am moderately skilled with coffescript, and only a novice when it comes to mocha/mocha-cakes, so I am most certainly doing something wrong in my code. Here is an example of a couple of the test cases that are failing:

```
require 'mocha-cakes'
should = require 'should'
restify = require 'restify'


Feature "Account API",
  "In order to have control over structured Account documents",
  "as a consumer of investment account information,",
  "I need a RESTful service API.", ->

    Scenario "GET /account/:userid", ->

      client = restify.createJSONClient
        url: "http://localhost:8080",
        version: "*"

      _e1 = null
      _r1 = null

      _e2 = null
      _r2 = null
      _d2 = null

      # GET non-existent account
      Given "I have not yet created the Account", ->
      When "I request the Account", (done) ->
        client.get "/account/99", (err, req, res, obj) ->
          _e1 = err
          _r1 = res
          done()
          err

      Then "it should respond with an error", ->
        _e1.should.be.ok
      And "the status code should be 404", ->
        _r1.should.have.status 404


      # GET existent account
      Given "I have created the Account", (done) ->
        client.post "/account", { userId: 1, accountType: 0, accountCategories: [], beneficiaries: [], accountOwner: { firstName: "Test", lastName: "User" } }, (err) ->
          done()
          err

      When "I request the Account", (done) ->
        client.get "/account/1", (err, req, res, obj) ->
          _e2 = err
          _r2 = res
          _d2 = obj
          done()
          err

      Then "it should responond with a document", ->
        _d2.should.be.ok
      And "it should have the userId 1", ->
        _d2.userId.should.eql 1
      And "it should have an accountOwner property", ->
        _d2.accountOwner.should.be.ok
      And "the status code should be 200", ->
        _r2.should.have.status 200
```

When I run this, my output is always the following:

> c:\Development\Clients\Pensco\AngularJS\Pensco\newaccountwizard.api>mocha
>   test/AccountAPITests.coffee -r should -R spec --compilers
>   coffee:coffee-script/register
>
> Feature: Account API
>
> ```
>     In order to have control over structured Account documents
>     as a consumer of investment account information,
>     I need a RESTful service API.
>
>
> Scenario: GET /account/:userid
>   ◦
>     - ◊ Given: I have not yet created the Account (pending)
>   ◦
>     1)  When: I request the Account
>   ◦
>     √  Then: it should respond with an error
>   ◦
>     √   And: the status code should be 404
>   ◦
>     2) Given: I have created the Account
>   ◦
>     3)  When: I request the Account
>   ◦
>     √  Then: it should responond with a document
>   ◦
>     √   And: it should have the userId 1
>   ◦
>     √   And: it should have an accountOwner property
>   ◦
>     √   And: the status code should be 200
> ```
>
> 6 passing (6s)   1 pending   3 failing
>
> 1) Feature: Account API
>
> ```
>     In order to have control over structured Account documents
>     as a consumer of investment account information,
>     I need a RESTful service API.
>
> Scenario: GET /account/:userid ◦  When: I request the Account:
>  Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded
> at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:139:19)
> at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
> ```
>
> 2) Feature: Account API
>
> ```
>     In order to have control over structured Account documents
>     as a consumer of investment account information,
>     I need a RESTful service API.
>
> Scenario: GET /account/:userid ◦ Given: I have created the Account:
>  Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded
> at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:139:19)
> at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
> ```
>
> 3) Feature: Account API
>
> ```
>     In order to have control over structured Account documents
>     as a consumer of investment account information,
>     I need a RESTful service API.
>
> Scenario: GET /account/:userid ◦  When: I request the Account:
>  Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded
> at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:139:19)
> at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
> ```

Now, I know that my REST calls via client.get/client.post occur almost instantaneously. When I remove the dones, and run without them, with the exception of the first run after restarting my restify service server, usually only the first or second `Then`/`And` fails, the rest succeed. There is a timing issue of maybe a few milliseconds, but definitely not 2000ms. I'm curious why my Givens and Whens suddenly start timing out when I throw in the `done()` calls.

I am pretty sure I am misunderstanding how mocha-cakes is transforming the coffescript Feature->Scenario->Given/When->Then/And/... into describe/it calls. I suspect that somehow the scope within which done applies is larger than it would seem to be given the nature of mocha-cakes script structure...I'm just not sure exactly what that scope is.

Answer (score 0):

I am also not familiar with mocha-cakes. I am using mocha/(lit)coffee to test restify. I have found it convenient to wrap my calls in promises, as latest mocha is promise-aware. Then I don't have to bother with "done". Also note you may need to call res.end() or res.resume() (See [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15533448/node-js-http-request-problems-with-connection-pooling))

For just "GET":

```
Promise = require('bluebird')  # or whatever, I presume
port = 8776                    # ditto

getHttpJson = (addr)->
  addr = normalizeUrl(addr)
  new Promise ( resolve, reject )->
    req = http.get(addr, _completeResponse(resolve) )
      .on( 'error', reject )
    req.end()
```

General case:

```
requestHttpJson = (method, addr, data)->
  if data?
    data = JSON.stringify(data)
  urlBits = getUrlBits(addr)
  new Promise (resolve, reject)->
    req = http.request(
      method: method
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json" }
      hostname: urlBits.hostname
      port: urlBits.port
      path: urlBits.pathname
    , _completeResponse(resolve) )
    req.on( 'error', reject )
    if data?
      req.write( data )
    req.end()

postHttpJson = (addr, data)->
  requestHttpJson('POST', addr, data)
putHttpJson = (addr, data)->
  requestHttpJson('PUT', addr, data)
deleteHttpJson = (addr, data)->
  requestHttpJson('DELETE', addr, data)
```

Break down address into components and add defaults. ("port" is a module global.)

```
getUrlBits = (addr)->
  bits = url.parse(addr)
  bits.port = bits.port || port
  bits.hostname = bits.hostname || 'localhost'
  bits.protocol = bits.protocol || 'http'
  return bits

normalizeUrl = (addr)->
  url.format(getUrlBits(addr))
```

Utility to parse body of request & resolve.

```
_completeResponse = (resolve)->
  (res)->
    body = []
    res.on 'data', (data)->
      body.push data
    res.on 'end', ->
      body = body.join ''
      content = if body == '' then null else JSON.parse(body)
      resolve([res,content])
```